# Why does setting margin auto center h2, but does not center object?

Tags: html, css

I have the fallowing HTML code that basically has an object element that displays a local PDF.  I would like this object element to be centered in its div.conainer.  I use margin:0 auto; and was expecting it to add margins on both sides of the object to center it.  However the Object has no margins.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <h2>TITLE OF THE THING</h1>
            <object data="somepdf.pdf" type="application/pdf"></object>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

With the fallowing CSS:

```
section{
    position:relative;
    background-color:#323776;
}

object{
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
}

h1{
    max-width: 100px;
    width: 80vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I have tried entering fixed values for margin such as 10px or 20vw.  when I give margin an exact value the object element has margins.  However it seems to me that auto should work.  Please educate me.

### Questions

1. Why are the margins of my object element zero?
2. Why does the margin auto center h2 but not the Object element?

I've attached a screen shot here to show you what I see.
[image]

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Should I delate this post and make a new post using the minimal example or delate the content of this post and re write it?

Comment: You should modify this question, not create another. As it is, it has no value to anyone. In order for your centering technique to work, your element needs to have a `display` property of `inline-block` and the parent should have a `width` property translatable to `px` (`%`, `px`, `em`, `vw`) but not abstract values like `initial` or `auto`.

Comment: I've change the question which i hope is a little more clear and useful.  It's not clear to me why the h2 element is centered however the object element is not.  Both elements are using the same margin: auto;

Comment: Try display: block rather than display: inline-block

Comment: Legin76 that works like a charm.  Thank you.

Comment: Does this meant that the <object> element's default display is something other than block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that the <object> element's default display is something other than block?

Yes; it's usually either inline or inline-block. Most embedded content elements in HTML are typically rendered as inline-level replaced elements. This includes `iframe`, `img` and `object`. You almost never see embedded content on its own line in an unstyled HTML page — when you do, it's likely because it's residing in its own `p` element apart from the surrounding text.

> 1. Why are the margins of my object element zero?

That's because auto horizontal margins are zeroed out on inline-level replaced elements. See sections [10.3.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width) of the spec. (Section [10.3.10](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inlineblock-replaced-width) simply links back to 10.3.2.)

> 2. Why does the margin auto center h2 but not the Object element?

See above.

Comment: This is a good / useful article on centring. https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/